# не могу получить ссылку методом get('href')

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup, python-3.7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем добрый день. Пытаюсь спарсить сайт, но не могу получить ссылку из `href` (получаю ответ `None`) по второй строке. Поставил сообщалку `print`, чтоб проанализировать строки супа и получаю:

```html
<a href="https://www.test.com/search/?q=%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%BD" rel="nofollow">Все новости </a>
<p><a href="http://www.test.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Персональный сайт">Персональный сайт</a>
```

Откуда взялся тег `p`, если строки абсолютно одинаковые?

Comment: Ну например из javascript-кода, который браузер выполняет, а вы не выполняете. Если вы пытаетесь парсить html, то нужно изучать именно исходный html-код, а не браузерное DOM-дерево

Comment: И не должно быть, потому что страница в значительной степени наполняется скриптами

Comment: то есть то что я вижу в браузере при просмотре кода это не есть факт?как же тогда строить парсинг.Если я ориентируюсь на это дерево,а оказывается из второй строчки не могу извлечь href по непонятным причинам

Comment: Ориентируйтесь не на дерево, а на исходный html-код. А если в исходном html-коде нет нужных вам данных — штош, ищите откуда они берутся на самом деле

Comment: ну я ориентируюсь на то что мне выдает СУП.Плюс смотрю по дереву в браузере.Как правильно получить html код?

Comment: Если речь про Jsoup, то он не умеет исполнять Javascript-код. Используйте другие инструменты, которые умеют выполнять Javascript. Дерево DOM может меняться из Javascript-кода, как уже говорили выше. [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1514937/edit) к вашему вопросу корректные метки, какой язык и какие библиотеки вы используете. Сейчас из вопроса не совсем понятно, о чем идет речь.

Comment: Использую питон 3.7 библиотеку import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')html  парсер

Comment: article_item = div_item_class.find("article")   получаю тег и в цикле парсю строки

Comment: Вот что выдал чат GPT.                                                                                                                                    Тег <a href> используется для создания гиперссылок на веб-странице, которые позволяют пользователям переходить на другие страницы или документы в Интернете. Атрибут href в теге <a> определяет URL-адрес, на который должна быть выполнена ссылка.

Comment: Тег <p><a href> используется для создания текста с гиперссылкой. Это означает, что текст, заключенный в тег <p> будет содержать гиперссылку, определенную внутри тега <a>.
В обоих случаях используется тег <a href>, но разница заключается в том, что в первом случае тег <a> используется самостоятельно и не содержится внутри другого тега, а во втором случае тег <a> находится внутри тега <p>.

Comment: но ведь в дереве браузера они одинаковы абсолютно

Comment: "одинаковы абсолютно" а по моему они разные, на скрине видно, что разные. Хотите получить ответ выкладывайте ваш код на реальный сайт, так мы можеи долго годать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: чем на скрине они отличаются?тем что первый имеет класс?ивсе.